# Write on external storage root in Android 10 targeting higher versions

Tags: android, storage

I needed some external app to edit files generated by my app, so I started saving them on the external root directory. Now I'm updating the target sdk, and I have to adapt the storage management. I came up with these 3 ideas:

- Save files on external dir dedicated for app: I haven't found a way to open files storaged in this path with external apps.
- Save files on external root directory: For Android 11 and higher, I can use `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, but it's not working on Android 10. I'm targeting Android 13, so I can't use the legacy storage flag.
- Save files with scoped storage: I haven't found a way to create an app folder inside of `/Documents` external folder, but I think this is the way to go.

Any more options? How can I implement the third option?

Answer (score 0):

To let your files be opened by an external app you need to implement ACTION_VIEW using a FileProvider for your file.

It does not matter where you store your file.